# What is the appropriate choice of hash family to make XOR homomorphism unlikely?

Tags: hash, universal-hash

Let's say $N \subseteq [n]$ is not empty. Is there a type of hash family $H = \{h : [n] \rightarrow \{0 , 1\}^k\}$, where $k = \theta(\log(n))$, to ensure that the following holds when $|N| > 1$?

$$\underset{h \in H}{\Pr}(h (\underset{t \in N}{\oplus}t) = \underset{t \in N}{\oplus}h(t)) \leq \frac{1}{2^k}$$

Comment: Any cryptographically secure hash function otherwise the pre-image resistance has gone!

Comment: @kelalaka Suppose I didn't care about pre-image resistance and I just wanted to ensure the property in my question. Would I be able to use something like just a 2-universal family of hash functions then?

Comment: Do you absolutely need it to be with xor? You can achieve $\Pr[ h(\sum t) = \sum h(t) ] =0$ where the addition is mod $p$ -- just define $h(x)=x+1$. Then the LHS is $1+\sum t $ and the RHS is $|N| + \sum t$, which are not equal unless $|N|=1 \pmod p$.

Comment: @Mikero Thanks for the suggestion. Actually xor was chosen specifically to avoid modular addition. The $t$ mentioned in my question are fairly large, and to avoid overflows in limited memory xor was selected instead.

Comment: Is the set $N$ or its size fixed? bounded above?